# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document

Tags: android, kotlin, xml-parsing

I am parsing xml file which i created already and store into internal storage.

Below is the code for create xml file:

```
        val xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer()
        val writer = StringWriter()
        val out = mContext.contentResolver.openOutputStream(backupFile)

            xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer)
            xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true)
            xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true)
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", PARENT1)
            xmlSerializer.attribute("", TOTAL_COUNT, List.size.toString())

            for (i in 0 until List.size) {
                var item = List.get(i)

                xmlSerializer.startTag("", CHILD)

                xmlSerializer.attribute("", CHILD1, item.add)

                xmlSerializer.attribute("", CHILD2, Utils.removeNonPrintable(item.body))

                xmlSerializer.attribute("", CHILD3, Utils.removeNonPrintable(item.name))

                xmlSerializer.endTag("", CHILD)
            }

            xmlSerializer.endTag("", PARENT1)
            xmlSerializer.endDocument()
            xmlSerializer.flush()


            val strData = writer.toString()
            out!!.write(strData.toByteArray())
            out.close()
```

Below code is for parsing xml file:

```
    var List = ArrayList<MsgModel>()
    val file = File(path)
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        val reader = InputStreamReader(inputStream, UTF8)
        val inSource = InputSource(reader)
        inSource.encoding = UTF8
        val dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        val db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
        db.setErrorHandler(SimpleErrorHandler())
        val doc = db.parse(inSource)

        val nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(CHILD)
            for (i in 0 until nl.length) {
                var item = DataModel()
                val e = nl.item(i) as Element

                item.child1 = getValue(e, CHILD1)
                item.child2 = getValue(e, CHILD2)
                item.child3 = getValue(e, CHILD3)

                List.add(item)
            }
```

I am getting error in this line `val doc = db.parse(inSource)`

Comment: Did you check if your XML document is correct, e.g. by using an external XML validator?

Comment: @user2340612 Yes.